# Changing Multiple values in MySQL with a single Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to change different column values of a table in one query, is that possible?

I tried something like this (just a guess):

```
<?php
$q="UPDATE tab SET name='samit' WHERE id='1' && set name='anju' where id='4'";
$run=mysql_query($q);
if($run){
echo 'updated';
}
else{
echo 'update failed';
}
?>
```

It's not working. I can do this using a loop, but a loop will increase operation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `JOIN`

```sql
UPDATE tab t1 JOIN tab t2
    ON t1.id = 1 AND t2.id = 4
   SET t1.name = 'samit',
       t2.name = 'anju'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a51e/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you'll have to use case like so:

```
UPDATE tab
    SET name = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'samit'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'anju'
    END
    WHERE id IN (1,4);
```

Still, i'd recommend against it and just run your queries with a loop; also, mysql_* is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It's propably not the best way but:

```
UPDATE tab
SET
name= IF(id='1', 'samit', name),
name= IF(id='4', 'anju', name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `tab`
IF(id= 1, "SET name= 'samit'", ''),
IF(id= 4, "SET name= 'anju'", '')
```

I hope this would work for you. Although i have not tested it yet but you can use `if` condition in update query